# how to convert Apache mod_rewrite rules to Microsoft URL Rewriter IIS7?

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis-7, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

can someone tell me how to convert apache iis7 mod_rewrite .htaccess file to the equivalent web.config in MS Url Rewriter?

Here is the .htaccess file I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

These look like WordPress rules.  WordPress understands and knows how to modify the IIS 7 web.config file automatically.  If you use the platform installer to install WordPress you don't have to worry about any of this:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

There is also an Apache Rewriter config import into Microsoft URL Rewriter.  And if you truly like Apache style syntax there is the URL Rewriter project provided by Managed Fusion, which supports Apache rules on IIS 6 and 7:

http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com